Why wont FireFox connect to a WSS even though ive added the CA to its Certificate Manager?
I am building a website that uses websockets and I wanted to make them secure. I used the following command to generate a self-signed certificate for HTTPS and WSS:
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
-keyout apache/build/certs/ow.key \
-out apache/build/certs/ow.crt \
-subj "/C=UK/ST=England/L=London/O=Company/CN=${HOST_IP}" \
-extensions v3_ca \
-config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf <(printf '[v3_ca]\nbasicConstraints=CA:TRUE\nsubjectAltName=IP:${HOST_IP}\n'))

I then add this certificate to FireFox's certificate manager under the authorities tab. It adds the certificate in with no issue and loads the website fine, however the WSS refuses to connect. It works great in Chrome and the WSS connects, but for some reason doesn't work in Firefox.
Looking in the developer console in Firefox I get the following error:
MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY

I'm relatively new to certificates and don't fully understand why it would work in Chrome but not Firefox.
How can I make Firefox trust this certificate and allow the WSS to connect?
